# Why is PyTorch inference non deterministic even when setting `model.eval()`

Tags: python, machine-learning, random, pytorch

I have fine-tuned a PyTorch transformer model using HuggingFace, and I'm trying to do inference on a GPU. However, even after setting `model.eval()` I still get slightly different outputs if I run inference multiple times on the same data.

I have tried a number of things and have done some ablation analysis and found out that the only way to get deterministic output is by also setting

```
torch.cuda.manual_seed_all(42)
```

(or any other seed number).

Why is this the case? And is this normal? The model's weights are fixed, and there are no undefined or randomly initialized weights (when I load the trained model I get the `All keys matched successfully` message), so where is the randomness coming from if I don't set the cuda seed manually? Is this randomness to be expected?

Comment: Do you have self-defined parameters that is not be identified as part of the module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`torch.use_deterministic_algorithms`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.use_deterministic_algorithms.html) to force non-deterministic modules to perform deterministically, where supported e.g:

```py
>>> a = torch.randn(100, 100, 100, device='cuda').to_sparse()
>>> b = torch.randn(100, 100, 100, device='cuda')

# Sparse-dense CUDA bmm is usually nondeterministic
>>> torch.bmm(a, b).eq(torch.bmm(a, b)).all().item()
False

>>> torch.use_deterministic_algorithms(True)

# Now torch.bmm gives the same result each time, but with reduced performance
>>> torch.bmm(a, b).eq(torch.bmm(a, b)).all().item()
True

# CUDA kthvalue has no deterministic algorithm, so it throws a runtime error
>>> torch.zeros(10000, device='cuda').kthvalue(1)
RuntimeError: kthvalue CUDA does not have a deterministic implementation...
```